# How do you properly configure a provider service in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What is the best practices or patterns to config a provider inside a `config` block like how `$locationProvider` and `$routeProvider` do?

As far as I know, only providers are configurable inside `config` blocks.

The following code block is how I want to do with my own custom provider.

```
.config([
  '$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', '$httpProvider',
  function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $locationProvider
      .html5Mode(true)
      .hashPrefix('!');

    $routeProvider.otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/'
    });

    $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
  }
])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very good explanations on providers, factories and services at the [official docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers#provider-recipe).

In a nutshell, you should create a provider and expose whatever methods you need, besides the `$get` method. Upon the config call, you can call any other method you have, and when the system inject the dependency, it's going to call the `$get` method.

Assembled a [simple Plnkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/HIfnH2?p=preview), but that's how it's goes:

**1. The provider**

```js
app.provider('myService', function() {
  var configuredValue;

  this.setValue = function(val) {
    configuredValue = val;
  };

  this.$get = function() {
    return {
      valueSettedByTheConfig: configuredValue
    };
  };
});
```

Here you created the provider for the `myService` service, exposing a `setValue` configuration method, as in `$locationProvider.html5Mode` or `$routeProvider.otherwise`.

**2. The configuration moment**

```js
app.config(function(myServiceProvider) {
  myServiceProvider.setValue('my configured value');
});
```

Here you configure you module, before it gets used, by calling the exposed `setValue` method.

Notice that we inject the provider (`myService*Provider*`), for during configuration phase, you can only inject providers, not services.

**3. The usage**

```js
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, myService) {
  $scope.name = myService.valueSettedByTheConfig;
});
```

And finally here you simply inject the service and Angular is going to call the provider's `$get` method to generate the instance, after the config phase.

Comment: Thanks a lot for a complete answer!